# How to implement Service Worker in Angular for app update notifications

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I have installed the angular service worker module and applied the appropriate code to the app module. I have an `updateComponent` that has the UI to notify the user that there's a new version available with an update button that will reload the page.

However, in a previous version of the service worker, the code to make the notification UI appear and become removed on button click (reload), was the following:

```
export class LogUpdateService {

  updateAvailable: boolean = false;

  constructor(updates: SwUpdate) {
    updates.available.subscribe(event => {
      // console.log('current version is', event.current);
      // console.log('available version is', event.available);
      this.updateAvailable = true;
    });
    updates.activated.subscribe(event => {
      // console.log('old version was', event.previous);
      // console.log('new version is', event.current);
    });
  }
}
```

In the latest version, `available` has been depreciated.

I have added the following which achieves the UI component notification appearing. When the `update` button in the notification component is clicked, the page is reloaded (as intended). However, the notification component is still present and doesn't disappear. This component is governed by an `ngIf` with the `updateAvailable` boolean from the service below.

```
export class AppUpdateService {

  updateAvailable: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private swUpdate: SwUpdate
  ) {

    swUpdate.checkForUpdate().then(() => {
      this.updateAvailable = true;
    });

  }
}
```

**Question**

Once the `update` button in the notification component has been clicked and the page has reloaded, why is `updateAvailable` still true? Is there another condition in the latest version of the service worker that checks if the update has been applied?

Answer (score 0):

The following seemed to work:

```
    this.swUpdate.versionUpdates.subscribe((event: VersionEvent) => {
      if (event.type === 'VERSION_READY') {
        // do stuff
      }
    });
```